# SharePoint REST - Why update Metadata returns 204 instead of 200?

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, sharepoint-api, dynamics-365

Using below endpoint we can update the metadata for specific file: https://domain.example.com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(URL)/ListItemAllFields

Why after updating metadata successfully API returns 204 instead of 200. Is it expected or there is any other way of updating metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Dynamics Web API Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607664.aspx#bkmk_update), the default is to update the data without returning the updated results.  This is why you are getting a Status Code of 204.  In order to get data returned, you will need to add `prefer:return=representation` header to your Web API call.  Adding the `prefer` header will return a Status Code of 200.

#### C# Example

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Helpers.GetSystemUrl(APIConnector.Application.Dynamics));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("prefer", "return=representation");
```

#### Typescript Example

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("PATCH", CONNECTION_URL, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
xhr.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");          
xhr.setRequestHeader("prefer", "return=representation");
```

Comment: This is true for CRM web api. But question is about SharePoint REST Api..

Comment: @ArunVinoth Clearly was not reading carefully enough.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint REST API does not return the updated item/object after updating it. It only returns status code 204 if the update request is successful.

If you want to get updated item/object, you have to make another GET request.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list name')/items(item id)
```